# Chat con Socket.io 2.0: ¿Cómo obtener una lista de sockets conectados junto su ID?

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

Quiero obtener una lista de todos los IDs y nicknames de los sokets (clientes) conectados.

He visto respuestas que van de versiones anteriores de socket.io y ya no son compatibles. También la idea de crear un array donde almacene un objeto con el Id y el nickname por cada socket, sin embargo, eso no es lo que quiero. Pienso que debe haber una manera más limpia y eficaz.

En la parte cliente tengo un input text para colocar el nickname y un botón para entrar al chat. En el evento onClick, emito el evento del socket para concertarse:

```
var nickname = $('#nickname').val()
socket.emit('user connected', nickname)
```

Y en el server, el listen del evento lo tengo así:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('user connected', (nickname) => {
    // Asigno el nickname
    socket.nickname = nickname
    // Emito evento para avisar a todos los sockets el nickname nuevo conectado
    socket.emit(`user connected`, nickname);
  })
}
```

Ahora quiero obtener la lista con los IDs y nicknames de usuarios conectados.

En la documentación encontré este método que devuelve los IDs:

```
  var io = require('socket.io')();
  io.of('/chat').in('general').clients(function(error, clients){
    if (error) throw error
    console.log(clients); // => [Anw2LatarvGVVXEIAAAD]
  })
```

Y funciona bien. Sólo me faltan los nicknames y he tenido problemas para ello.

He intentado:

```
io.sockets.clients()

// y tambien
io.sockets.clients().connected
```

Pero retornan un objeto muy largo con mucha información.

¿Existe un modo simple y eficaz para obtener también los nickname?

Answer (score 2):

quizá no sea la mejor opción pero podrias crear un array en el server para ir guardando la información especifica de cada socket.

```
var clients = [ ];
```

y por cada nuevo socket que ingresa crear un objeto y setear la información que necesitas.

```
socketInfo = {
           socketId       : socket.id,
           socketNickName : socket.nickname
         };

clients.push(socketInfo);
```

de esta forma podrías tener organizada la información especifica que te interesa de cada nuevo socket y si necesitas pasar la lista de usuarios conectados no tendrías un objeto tan grande, y sabrías bien que información es la que permitís que sea visible.

Saludos.

Comment: Esta pregunta sale cada cierto tiempo en los canales oficiales en gitter y en slack, y esta solución que Ricardo pone es la forma de hacerlo.